# Mathematical areas that are applied to Rubiks Cube solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, optimization

I had seen about Group Theory being applied to rubik's cube and infact the solution algorithms are also based on group theory...
I want to know whether other mathematical fields like "optimization" or "number theory" is also applied to this puzzle in order to find the answer in minimum number of steps...
Thanks

Comment: See this http://www.cube20.org, this http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3435, and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube which suggest that some group theory, plus careful search strategies and fast computer algorithms can be used.